# Can't change size element in gridbaglayout

Tags: java, layout

I want to set width of `jbutton` and `jdate chooser = 2` cell in `gridbaglayout`. I try use `weightx`, `weighty`, `gridwidth`, `gridweight` in my code to set size `jbutton` and `jdatechooser` but can't.

This is the [jdatechooser](http://www.toedter.com/download/jcalendar-1.4.zip) library.

And this my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

public class SearchRoomFrm extends JFrame {

final private String[] listTypeRoom = { "thường", "hạng trung", "VIP" };

private JDateChooser txtStartDate;
private JDateChooser txtEndDate;
private JComboBox cbTypeRoom;
private JButton btnSearchRoom;
private JTable tbRoom;
private JButton btnXong;

public SearchRoomFrm() {
    super("Search Room");
    txtStartDate = new JDateChooser();
    txtEndDate = new JDateChooser();
    cbTypeRoom = new JComboBox(listTypeRoom);
    btnSearchRoom = new JButton("Search");
    tbRoom = new JTable();
    btnXong = new JButton("Xong");

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

    // Row 1
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    content.add(new JLabel("Start date: "), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    content.add(txtStartDate, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    content.add(btnSearchRoom, c);

    // Row 2
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    content.add(new JLabel("End date: "), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    content.add(txtEndDate, c);

    // Row 3
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    content.add(new JLabel("Type room: "), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    content.add(cbTypeRoom, c);

    // Row 4
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 3;
    content.add(tbRoom, c);

    this.setContentPane(content);
    this.pack();
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - this.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - this.getHeight()) / 2);
    this.setLocation(x, y);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchRoomFrm frm = new SearchRoomFrm();
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Set the width to what?  Have you tried `fill`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am newbiew and to follow https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html but with my case, i can't change size, you can edit my code to set size of JButton to 2 cell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like...

[image]

Which is achieved using something like...

```
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridheight = 2;
content.add(btnSearchRoom, c);
c.gridheight = 1;
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nceeylk.png

My ideal is similar picture. To do that, I must add the first row is cells has title and set size for it, because I think size of the first row will decide the size of cells row below.

Thanks so much for your help :D